# "it needs to be empty" / "it needs to empty" / "it needs emptying"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Which one of the following is correct?

> - This memory is full, it needs **to be empty.**
> - This memory is full, it needs **to empty**.
> - This memory is full, it needs **emptying**.

it should be *passive voice*, so I think first one is the right one. but third one sounds well.

Comment: i think _it needs emptying_ is fine. this is an apparent active voice though the meaning is kind of passive as in _the car’s dirty. It needs washing_ which means _it needs to be washed_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what it means for **memory** to be **emptied** (normally we say *cleared*), so let's change it to "clothes washer" (a machine for washing clothes).

> 1. This clothes washer needs to be empty.
> 2. This clothes washer needs emptying.
> 3. This clothes washer needs to empty.
> 4. This clothes washer needs to be emptied.

In #1, **empty** is an adjective.

In #2, **emptying** is a nominal (gerund).

In #3, **to empty** is an intransitive verb, meaning "to discharge or release one's contents".

Only if the thing is capable of emptying itself can we use #3.

In #4, an implied someone does the emptying. **to be emptied** is a passive form of the transitive verb "to empty", meaning "to remove all contents from".

Comment: Thank you, your example is find, and it is covered what I asked. regarding empty and clear, I was talking about "flash memory", and I used "empty" because we "empty recycle bin" on Operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

```
This memory is full, it needs to be emptied
```

This uses the passive *to be emptied*